# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (8,)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I've been following the step by step tutorial for this web app for plant disease detection and there's an error in this part where it suppose to show the line graph but there's an error at the line 3 which said "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (6,) and (8,)" I hope someone can help me to solve this thank you in advance Im just a beginner in coding so it will be a huge help for me.

```
n = 6
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(np.arange(1, n + 1),history.history['loss'], label = 'train_loss')
plt.plot(np.arange(1,n + 1), history.history['val_loss'], label = 'val_loss')
plt.plot(np.arange(1,n + 1), history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc = "best")
plt.savefig('/content/drive/My Drive/PlantDRecognition/performance.jpg')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Add the python code also. The part where you provide input the values.

Comment: you probably need `(1,6)` and `(1,8)` instead, so try reshaping both of them with numpy

Comment: Why is `n=6`?  Does that have anything to do with `history.history`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the the length of `history.history['loss']` and `n` are not equal.

Actually, `x` values of [matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y)](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) are optional and default to `range(len(y))`. You only need

```py
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label = 'train_loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label = 'val_loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
```

If you want `x` to start with 1,

```py
plt.plot(range(1, len(history.history['loss'])+1), history.history['loss'], label = 'train_loss')
plt.plot(range(1, len(history.history['val_loss'])+1), history.history['val_loss'], label = 'val_loss')
plt.plot(range(1, len(history.history['val_accuracy'])+1), history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')
```